# Spring Boot Filter URL Mapping

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

The request mapping for my controller is something like this:

```
/hospital/{hospitalId}/department/{departmentId}/doctors
```

And i tried to add the pattern for authentication required filter:

```
/hospital/*/department/*/doctors
```

But it's not working. It's there a chance to make this work?

Comment: Is there any URL of the shape `/hospital/*/department/....` that you would like to keep public? Because the easiest solution would be to just filter `/hospital/**`, or `/hospital/*/**`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping for a filter isn't a Ant-style mapping as you're used to in Spring, but a mapping as defined in the [Servlet specification](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-3.1/Final/servlet-3_1-final.pdf). In section 12.2 it says:

> the following syntax is used to define mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the
>     application's context root, i.e., requests of the form http://host:port//. In this case the path info is ’/’ and the servlet path and context path is empty string (““).
> - A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.

`/hospital/*/department/*/doctors` only meets the criteria of the final bullet so it's treated as an exact match.

The best that you can do within confines of the servlet specification is to use `/hospital/*` and then do some secondary matching in your filter's code. You could use Spring Framework's `org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher` to do so.